# My Tensorflow DNN Classifier is very slow to start predicticting results

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, classification

I'm running the [Tensorflow tf.estimator Quickstart example](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator) on a Raspberry Pi 3. It works well, however the prediction is very slow.

The instruction `predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn))` takes seconds to return.

It's a problem for me because I want to predict a simple tuple immediately after I receive it from my sensors, I cannot batch the predictions.

My model_dir is a tmpfs folder (something in RAM) so I don't think it's related to IO latency. Perhaps the network is built every time, I don't know.

I'm probably doing something wrong, do you know how to run TensorFlow predictions on the same classifier in a short time ?

Comment: What network architecture are you using?

Comment: Have you tried running `classifier.predict` multiple times? Usually the first prediction takes a lot longer than succeeding calls

Comment: @GPhilo It's the example. I'm using a Deep Neural Network with 3 layers and respectively 10, 20, and 10 hidden units.

Comment: @BlueSun Yes because I want to run it multiple times. It doesn't seem to get faster.